# SQL Subquery greater than/less than operators

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm currently trying to simply query `jobname` and `jobid` via a `GROUP BY` function. I employ a subquery with `COUNT(jobID) >2`. Despite this, the output is still displaying values of 2. I understand I can use HAVING with this, but I am genuinely interested as to why this is not working.

```
SELECT EmployeeType.jobName, COUNT(Employee.JobID) FROM Employee, EmployeeType WHERE (Employee.jobID = EmployeeType.jobID) AND (SELECT COUNT(Employee.jobID) FROM Employee) > 2 GROUP BY EmployeeType.JobName;
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your subquery has no relationship with the outer query. When that subquery is executed, it just queries `SELECT COUNT(Employee.jobID) FROM Employee` for each record being evaluated. The value of that query is greater than 2, so every record gets included.

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should just use a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT EmployeeType.jobName, COUNT(Employee.jobID)
FROM Employee, EmployeeType
WHERE Employee.jobID = EmployeeType.jobID
GROUP BY EmployeeType.JobName
HAVING COUNT(Employee.jobID) > 2
```

Comment: @Micheal, Suggesting you to use [ANSI JOIN syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support).

Comment: Agreed. If I were writing this myself, I would use an INNER JOIN. I just didn't want to change OP's query too much from what they have, so as to focus on the HAVING clause.

Comment: @Micheal Gunter, ok. got it

Comment: @VenkataramanR: PSA: "Micheal" is not a name. :) (Actually, it is a name in Irish and Scottish Gaelic, but 95%+ of the people you'll meet with this name spell it with an "ae".)

Comment: Got it. Sorry for my typo. I googled and found Michael Jackson, Michael Jordon :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not that Michael's answer is wrong, but using commas in the `FROM` clause should be totally discouraged.  So, I'm providing alternative answers.

First, the correct way to write the query in the 21st Century is:

```
SELECT et.jobName, COUNT(*)
FROM Employee e JOIN
     EmployeeType et
     ON e.jobID = et.jobID
GROUP BY et.JobName
HAVING COUNT(e.jobID) > 2;
```

Also note the use of table aliases.

*If `JobName` is unique in `EmployeeType`*, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select et.jobName,
       (select count(*)
        from employee e
        where e.jobId = et.jobId
       ) as cnt
from employeeType;
```

You would then use a subquery to filter for the counts you want.

Comment: Agreed. If I were writing this myself, I would use an INNER JOIN. I just didn't want to change OP's query too much from what they have, so as to focus on the HAVING clause.